# DrawText WinAPI Not Showing Result

Tags: c++, c

I tried to use the Windows API DrawText() to draw a string on current program's console Window, the program is suppose(I think) to draw a "Hello World" in green color(0x33CC33), but I don't get any result showing up, I don't know where I did wrong.

Here's the piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(void) {
    RECT Rect;
    SetConsoleTitleA("Win32CPPTest");
    HWND WinHandle = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", "Win32CPPTest");
    if (WinHandle == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to Find Target Window Hande.\n");
        return GetLastError();
    };
    HDC WinDC = GetWindowDC(WinHandle);
    if (WinDC == NULL) {
        printf("Failed To Get Target Window DC.\n");
        return GetLastError();
    };
    GetClientRect(WinHandle, &Rect);    //get the RECT structure from target handle 
    SetTextColor(WinDC, 0x33CC33);      //set text color to green
    SetBkMode(WinDC, TRANSPARENT);      //set background mix mode
    Rect.left = 40;                     //set font format
    Rect.top = 10;
    DrawTextA(WinDC, "Hello World!", -1, &Rect, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_NOCLIP);    //this function call is not showing anything on console window
    DeleteDC(WinDC);    //I set a breakpoint here so the HDC structure won't be destory
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: DrawText is for a GUI. WriteConsole is used to write to a console.

Comment: The is an entire family of console functions for color, position, etc. Newer versions of Windows 10 support escape sequences ala VT100.

Comment: A console window is owned by a separate process, used to be lsass.exe, it is conhost.exe on all modern Windows versions.  Its primary role is to act as a security boundary, preventing other processes from doing things like reading a password back from the console buffer.  Stops shenanigans like this as well.

Comment: Thank you all! I see the problem now,I will consider to create a separate window to do this process.

Comment: I change the code and it now works on google chrome brower, thank you! @HansPassant